# mocha+shouldjs Object Assertion has no method 'indexOf'

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, should.js

I'm using mochajs + should-promised as testing framework.

I'm trying to test an bluebird promise and I get

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Object #<Assertion> has no method 'indexOf'
    at Assertion.<anonymous> ([app path]\node_modules\sh
ould\lib\ext\string.js:22:32)
```

Test:

```
obj.certainMethod(opts).should.be.eventually.an.Array();
```

If I run manually the method I get a JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "55ce4fc18a051bc4a1aed7f5",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "61d6d6a9-5864-4c48-8377-04e9f4260112",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,763.34",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 30,
    "range": [1,2,3]
  },
  {
    "_id": "55ce4fc1a5b9b94d9d3888f5",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "08f6ce47-997d-453d-a16a-030a28726191",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,805.68",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 31,
    "range": [1,2,3]      
  }
]
```

Any ideas of what's wrong?

Comment: From your stack track it looks either it is not that test failed or not that stack trace. .Array does not use in any way string assertions.

Comment: How do I tell shouldjs to eval anarray assertion? @denbardadym And yes, the test is not failing but throwing that error